# How to deal with no-transactional service during transaction?

Tags: sql, transactions, finance, bitcoin, distributed-transactions

Suppose that I have a SQL-transactional financial system, but during transaction it calls external non-SQL service.

**How to deal with e.g. power loss when we don't have if the external call was successful or not?**

Let's imagine that on SQL-database and a Bitcoin wallet making transaction.

1. Start SQL transaction
2. Decrase user amount cash
3. Send user cash somewhere throught Bitcoin wallet
4. Commit

The power loss between step 3 and 4, will prevent commiting transaction (none decrase of user cash), but actually sending our money from wallet.

Second scenerio is to decrase user cash and commit before calling external service. But, when power loss will occur after external service fail (not actualy sended) money, we don't make it to return user funds after external service fail (suppose that Bitcoin wallet is down).

Currently, I am decrasing money and marking transaction as "in progress" (and commiting that) before call to external service, then if external service responds OK, i mark everything as successfuly finished.

But, at power loss I can still stay in situation that some transaction after power loss is marked as "in progress", money decrased, but I have to look manualy on Bitcoin wallet/blockchain transactions if money actually was sended.

Is there better way to manage transactions in this situation? Is it possible to solve in any way without possibilty to check in future time if our external call was successful or not? (like I can check all past transactions in blockchain)

Answer (score 3):

Welcome to the wonderful world of Distributed Transactions! After working on them for many many years at various places (MS, Google, etc), Pat Helland came to the conclusion that there *is no silver bullet* and that the best you can do is go for 'Eventual Consistency'.

You're making a good start with the 'In Progress' flag. Without knowing the details of the remote transaction (i.e. what steps you have to go through, what data is available at the completion of each) I can't tell you how to do it exactly so here's some generalities.

If you can get a transaction id from the remote site before the transaction is committed, then when you gat it update your local db with this transaction Id. When the remote transaction is completed, update a 'Complete' flag on your local db.

You will now have a number of possible states. Only two need attention:

1. InProgress set, not Completed, no TransactionId: remnote transaction
   needs to be started and completed
2. InProgress set, not completed, Transaction Id exists: may be
   committed in remote site; contact it to check whether that
   transaction has been completed; if not complete (or go back to first
   state and do the whole thing)

That's an outline. As I say I don't know the ins-and-outs of how a bitcoin transaction is completed, but I hope it gives you an idea.